# bxslider javascript slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

having trouble implementing this bxslider slider. first things first, the images are all visible? how do i make this look like an actual slider?

you can see the issue live here; http://danielmdesigns.com/windermere/index.html

otherwise, i've done exactly what the website told me to =/

JS Script

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="bxslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/Couple%20on%20Lounge%20Chair_Towneclub.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/Man%20on%20Bench_Towneclub.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/Picnic%20Couple_Towneclub.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/Small%20Golf_Towneclub.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.bxslider{
height:600px;
width:auto;
background-color:#c41230;
/*background-image: url(images/imagescroll_1.png);*/
background-size:cover;
position:relative;
top:95px;
}
```

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

I am an amateur, but all help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I looked at your page, and couldn't find the call to .bxSlider in script tags above the </body>. Did I miss something?

Comment: @TimSPQR, i noticed it is in head tag. However, reference to "/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js" is going to a 404

Comment: Then there is the problem. You need to download the.js file to your server and make sure the link in the header is pointing to the right file.

Comment: thanks a bunch @TimSPQRj - i noticed a few mistakes, including what you stated, and corrected those. however, i still see no change. any chance you could take another look?

Comment: Ok, I might see the problem.  Take your JS text above out of the js file, and put it in a document ready function above your </body> tag.

Comment: so put "$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});" into another $( document ).ready(function() {}); - is that correct?

Comment: It looks like you are loading bxslider twice, one from /js/jquery.bxslider.min.js and from the root of your site bxslider.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add a type to the script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I simplified your entire page, and changed the images, uploaded this file to my website and it works fine. So your problem is probably in the way you are calling the files in the head, and the lack of the bxSlider function in the script above the `</body>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>testslider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
  <link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
.bxslider {
  height: 600px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #c41230;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>        

</head>
<body>
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src='http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130627150007/disney/images/a/aa/Goofy-11.jpg' /></li>
    <li><img src="https://www.irononsticker.com/images/2012/09/05/Pluto%20Mickey.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.getcartoonwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Minnie-Mouse-4.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://dliq60eur0hds.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/yosemite-perfect-3-days-half-dome.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmm... i've took everything here, even your images and i am still getting the same result. dang. want to take another look? i've pretty much copied and pasted exactly what you have here and the images still stack. thanks so much for your help on this @TimSPQR

Comment: The jquery.bxSlider.jx and the jquery.bxslider.css need to be in the same subdirectory as the .html file in the above situation. Later, after get it to work, you can slowly start moving things around, one at a time.

Comment: i have done this. thanks for your help. i'll keep chippin' away at it.

Comment: thanks again for your help bud. somehow, i just figured it out. thanks again.